# How to stop external JS from being load from specific layout in Magento?

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, external-script, customization

Magento provides a way to include external js or css using following method.

```
<css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
```

[Reference](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/layouts/xml-manage/)

But  i can't find any references about how to stop/remove them from specific pages layouts.

Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<remove>` tag in your specific layout file to remove external css/js .

You can as below in your layout file.

```
<head>
   <remove src="your-css-or-js-path"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Yes i already tried this way but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: did u get Ans for this